# Handlebars if/else rendering both branches

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a simple if/else statement in my handlebars template (in an Ember app), but for some reason both the if and else branches are being rendered.

Here is the section of code:

```
{{#if loading}}
    <p>Loading</p>
{{else}}
    {{#if loaded}}
        loaded
        <p><button {{action "play" this}}>Play</button><p>
    {{else}}
        not loaded
        <p><button {{action "load" this}}>Load</button><p>
    {{/if}}
{{/if}}
```

Initially, only the `else` branch is rendered, but when I load the sound and set its `loaded` key to true, both the `if` and `else` branches are rendered.

This is the method that changes the `loaded` property of the sound:

```
load: function() {
    var media = new window.Media(this.get("normalizedPath"), this._finishedPlaying.bind(this), this._finishedPlaying.bind(this)),
        loadPromise;

    this.set("media", media);
    this.set("loading", true);

    if(media.load) {
        loadPromise = media.load();
    }
    else {
        loadPromise = RSVP.resolve(this);
    }

    return loadPromise.then(function() {
        this.set("loading", false);
        this.set("loaded", true);
        return this;
    }.bind(this));
},
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might want to supply the code, which handles the loaded states :)

Comment: @MartinElvar I don't see why that would be necessary. Is there anything I could be doing to the `loaded` property that would cause the handlebars to render both branches? I'll add the code anyway though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got bad html here, you are missing the closing p tags, and instead have opening p tags.

Comment: Thank you. That was the issue. I'll accept the answer once I can.